# Apply the same matplotlib cmap function with a specific range for different data with different value ranges

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I am trying with matplotlib to achieve that I get consistent colors for a specific value range across different data sets. So, I want to give a minimum and maximum value range and apply a cmap function based on this range which I can apply to different data sets and which give the same color for the same value and which does not adapt to the range of values of the particular data set. However, I need to get the colors from a function when I give some values and not apply this range to the `plt.imshow()` function since I cannot use that for my case. I want to demonstrate my point here:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset_a = np.linerange(0,1000)
dataset_b = np.linerange(0,10)

pal = plt.get_cmap("viridis")

colors_a = pal(dataset_a)
colors_b = pal(dataset_b)
```

So, I do not want to have the full range of colors in the colors_a and colors_b object but the same range applied for both datasets.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: You are missing the normalize step: `colors_a = pal(Normalize(dataset_a, vmin=0, vmax=2000))`

Answer (score 1):

You can set the min/max values of `imshow` with the `vmin`/`vmax` parameters (cf. [`imshow` documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) ):

```
plt.imshow(DATA, vmin=0, vmax=1)
```